# route for url-parameters in the style ?var1=trolo&var2=lolo instead of /var1/var2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing a webapp with Laravel and got a URL which can contain up to 8 parameters (its a permalink-structure for a table with a lot of filters). Since all of them are optional I'd like to use the traditional URL-style:

www.mydomain.com/products?var1=trolo&var2=lolo&var3=lol

Is that possible with Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely possible.

You need to assign the `/products/` to a Controller method ( Or maybe the controller itself ) and access individual parameters inside the methods using `Input::get('var1');` I have used something like this in my own project to display stuff in pages `( users/?page=1....&stuff )`